# Is it possible to update a MYSQL Table from a Microsoft SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

Hi I am looking to run an update on a Remote MYsql Table (update Stock Levels) but the data I have is in a Local Microsoft SQL Table.

I currently process all my data locally in Microsoft SQL and normally using ssis just truncate then repopulate the relevant Remote MYSQL tables, This works fine but is slow and I dont want to do it 4 times a day.

can someone point me in the right direction for a SSIS tool or a way in Microsoft SQL to run an UPDATE query that will join a local MIcrosoft SQL table and a remote MYsql Table.

Thanks.

John.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a Linked Server (under Server Objects) on MS SQL that points to the MySQL Server.  Then use Synonyms to point to the remote tables.

You will probably need to use ODBC to make the connection.  First, download and install the MySQL ODBC driver from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/.  Then you will need to create a System ODBC Source using the new driver.

Comment: Thanks I already have the driver as I use a data transformation task to copy the data in the first place, Didnt think of setting up a linked server, I assume I can then run my update query as if the table is local.  thanks Ill give that a go.

Comment: You are correct.  Once you set up a synonym, you'll be able to run it as if it was local.  Good luck

Comment: Hi I set up the linked server thanks for the tip :) if i run a select query if works great. however if i try to run a update or insert query i get  OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "CRELOADED" returned message "Data provider or other service returned an E_FAIL status.".

Comment: fixed :) there were some null values in my date column in the mysql table gave them some values and they worked, I saw this on the web but thought as I wasnt updating the date field it wouldnt matter (it Did)